# cannot generate tables from specific module in spring boot modular project

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, module, spring-data-jpa, path

hibernate cannot generate all tables in spring boot modular project.
Sometables from specific module cannot be created,
I think class main does not know the path of the module and its models.

Comment: You think right. Check the package structure and read how @EntityScan annotation works.

Comment: i already made @EntityScan and i put the model packages path like this: @EntityScan({"x.model","y.model"})

Comment: You are saying that only few tables not generated? Another cause could be that some tables can't be created due to wrong definitions of entity classes. Please share those entities in the question as formatted code snippets. And also error messages from the startup log (if any).